# Issues Capturing Gray Scale Image using cv2 python interface to OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

I'm trying to capture gray scale images from an Imaging Source monochromactic camera (DMK 23UU45) in linux using openCV through the Python interface cv2 (v 2.4.8).

I am able to initialize the camera capture class via cv2.VideoCapture; however, the only properties that are currently recognized are the images size and width:

```
>>> cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
>>> cam1.get(3)
>>> 1280.0
>>> cam1.get(4)
>>> 960.0
```

If I try to get the status of other properties I get an error:

```
>>> cam1.get(1)
>>> HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Unable to get property <unknown property string>(16) - Invalid argument
-1.0
```

I think this is an issue because I believe the instance of VideoCapture class by default tries to convert the image to RGB3. I used the following code to read and save an image:

```
>>> flg, img = cam1.read()
>>> cv2.imwrite('/path/to/save/image.png', img)
```

The saved image looks like:
Ok, evidently I need more street cred to post a picture. Basically, the picture has three copies of the image and they are not at full resolution.

Not sure if it is of consequence, but when I initialize an instance of the VideoCapture class for the camera I get the following:

```
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable convert to requested pixfmt
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
```

Again, thank you for your time and consideration!!

Comment: what is the shape of img?  Do print img.shape.  In OpenCV, images are just ndarrays.

Comment: @ballsdotballs The image is (960, 1280, 3). Thanks!

Comment: seems like you're getting an image then. does it work if you save it as a .jpeg instead of a .png?  also, try showing the image in matplotlib and see if it looks correct.

Comment: @ballsdotballs I'm definitely getting the image. I think the problem is that it's trying to read the image as if it were RGB3. So I'm getting three copies of the image. Since I can't post the image here I have put it on imgur.com: http://imgur.com/l8RuBAn
It seems like it's dividing the 12 bits by 3 and assigning to R, G, and B causing three identical images of smaller size. I'm unable to tell it that it is a gray scale image. Thanks Balls.Balls for your help!